# Heroku app to access postgres database and both to communicate to each other

Tags: java, sql, heroku, web

My Heroku Java web app is not accessing the Postgres database and the command Heroku `pg:info` just showing `Tables:0 ; Rows:0` even though my `data.yml` file in Eclipse is populated.

I have tried to figure out what is wrong but still do not know what to do. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

A Java application on Heroku needs to connect to the database using the URL set as the `DATABASE_URL` config var. The code for parsing this might look something like:

```
private Connection getConnection() throws URISyntaxException, SQLException {
  URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

  String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
  String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
  int port = dbUri.getPort();

  String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ":" + port + dbUri.getPath();

  return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
}
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I have created a new java file called DbConnection.java and inserted the above code. Should I replace "DATABASE_URL"  and "jdbc:postgresql://" with my own ones or just leave the way it is ? Thanking you.

Comment: It depends. Are you using Play! framework? If not, what framework are you using?

Comment: Hi Joe, I have finally solved my database problem by using MySQL database instead of Postgres database. Every thing is now fine, thanks